# Linking sharepoint documents to vsts work items

Tags: sharepoint, azure-devops

My company currently uses Jira and Confluence. In this setup, it is very easy to link a Jira ticket to a Confluence page, via a simple search inside the create link dialog.

We're now looking at moving to VSTS Work Items and Sharepoint. I'm wondering whether VSTS Work Items and Sharepoint are strongly integrated as well. Is it easy to insert a link in a VSTS Work Item to the latest version of a Sharepoint document?

Comment: Do you clear it?

Answer (score 0):

The VSTS isn’t integrated with on-premise SharePoint, but you can add the link to the work item (Hyperlink type). So, they aren’t strongly integrated.

Answer (score 0):

as workaround in Azure DevOps you can add a link to work item's description (enter to Description field, use icon "Create link" and paste this link to window which appears).