# Showing list of VSTS work items in Sharepoint document

Tags: sharepoint, azure-devops, jira, confluence

In a Confluence page, you can show a list of Jira items via a JQL query.

I'm looking at migrating to VSTS work items and Sharepoint. In Sharepoint, is it possible to show a list of VSTS work items on a page? How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking sharepoint documents to vsts work items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882156/linking-sharepoint-documents-to-vsts-work-items)

Comment: @DanielMann That is not a duplicate. I know, because I wrote that question :-) The other question asks about referring from VSTS work item to a Sharepoint page, while this question asks about referring from a Sharepoint page to VSTS work items. So the other question is not actually related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Work Items Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items) that could retrieve work item data from VSTS, so you can [access external data with REST in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-access-external-data-with-rest-in-sharepoint).